# Why doesn't part of my code run at the end of a function?

Tags: python

I'm creating a program that generates a random series of pipe characters to create a block of pipes. At the end of my ranPipe() function, there is a makeshift converter that changes the text representing a pipe character to the character. For some reason, this doesn't seem to run -- testing it with print()s both inside the for loop of the converter and outside (just at the end of the function), it doesn't seem to run (or at least, it doesn't print).

I cannot just create a new function for the conversion, as it relies on variables used in ranPipe(), and I'm not very good with global variable declarations, so it causes more problems than it solves. It also must be referenced point of the ranPipe() function, because it should go after the checks seen earlier on in the code.

Why would this be, and how can I fix it? 
(Code below)

```
import random

finCheck = 0
pipeNums = {
    ##Note: Structure of values is icon, upcon, downcon, leftcon, rightcon
    "vertCon": "║1100",
    "horiCon": "═0011",
    "leftCornUpper": "╔0101",
    "rightCornUpper": "╗0110",
    "leftCornLower": "╚1001",
    "rightCornLower": "╝1010",
    "vertConMidL": "╠1101",
    "vertConMidR": "╣1110",
    "horiConMidN": "╦0111",
    "horiConMidS": "╩1011",
    "cross": "╬1111"
}

def ranPipe(north, south, left, right):
    ##Generates a random piece
    curPipe = random.choice(list(pipeNums))

    ##Resets piece check
    finCheck = 0

    ##Start of piece check looop
    while finCheck < 3:
        ##If the piece doesn't match previous piece, regen.
        while (curPipe[1] == "1" and prePipe[2] == "0") or (curPipe[3] == "1" and prePipe[4] == "0") or (curPipe[4] == "1" and prePipe[3] == "0"):
            curPipe = random.choice(list(pipeNums))
        ##Adds to check total when this completes
        finCheck += 1

        ##Additional checks for edge pieces.
        while True:
            if north == 1:
                while curPipe[1] == "1":
                    curPipe = random.choice(list(pipeNums))
                return curPipe
            elif south == 1:
                while curPipe[2] == "1":
                    curPipe = random.choice(list(pipeNums))
                return curPipe
            elif left == 1:
                while curPipe[3] == "1":
                    curPipe = random.choice(list(pipeNums))
                return curPipe
            elif right == 1:
                while curPipe[4] == "1":
                    curPipe = random.choice(list(pipeNums))
                return curPipe
            break

        ##Adds to check total when this completes
        finCheck += 1

        ##Runs one more general check. Adds if it passes, otherwise all check points are removed and it repeats.
        while True:
            if (curPipe[1] == "1" and prePipe[2] == "0") or (curPipe[3] == "1" and prePipe[4] == "0") or (curPipe[4] == "1" and prePipe[3] == "0"):
                finCheck = 0
                curPipe = random.choice(list(pipeNums))
            else:
                finCheck += 1
                break

    ##Converts the value of the current pipe to its value rather than its name    
    conChart = ['║', '═', '╔', '╗', '╚', '╝', '╠', '╣', '╦', '╩', '╬']
    for x in range(conChart):
        if curPipe == pipeNums[x]:
            curPipe = conChart[x]

def digDig(length, width):
    print("What length do want your pipes to be?")
    length = int(input("Note: The length and width of your creation may vary, as it is counted in number of characters rather than a definite measure.\n"))
    width = int(input("And the width?\n"))

    ##Start of code, top corner
    prePipe = random.choice(list(pipeNums))
    print(prePipe)

    ##Top line
    for x in range(length):
        print(ranPipe(1, 0, 0, 1))
```

(I appreciate that my code is (a) not very pythonic in places, and (b) incomplete. While I always appreciate help in making my code more efficient, I am specifically asking for help with the problem with my converter, and would prefer for the focus to be on that rather than my convoluted code).

Comment: There are a lot of `return`s in the code before the  last part. If one of them is executed, the function execution ends there.

Comment: have you tried calling `digDig` ? dumb question I know... just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Your posted code defines two variables and two functions, and then quits.  The code is not at all minimal, and you haven't traced the control flow of ranPipe.  You generally exit the `while True` loop by leaving the function, so you don't reach the conversion code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, you call `ranPipe` with the parameter `north=1`, so when you get to the third while loop, you have the line `if north == 1:` which evaluates to true, resulting in the return being executed and the function being exited.

Just as an addendum of things I saw while going through your code:
You are using `prePipe` in your function `ranPipe`, but haven't defined it in that function; you only defined it in digDig, and  you're using `for x in range(conChart)`, but the `range` function accepts an integer: you need to specify `len(conChart)`.